# "invalid character value for cast" error on INSERT via UCanAccess

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I'm getting the error

> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.6 data exception: invalid character value for cast

when I run this code:

```
 package aoa;
    import java.sql.*;
    public class Aoa {


        public static void main(String[] args)  {
             Connection cn;
      Statement st;
      ResultSet re;
      String ID ="username"; 
      String NAME="password";  


      try{

        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\MUHAMMAD SHAHAB\\STUD1.accdb");
        st = cn.createStatement();
       String q = "INSERT INTO STUD1 ([Id], [Address]) VALUES (?, ?)";
    PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement (q);
    pst.setString(1, "a");
    pst.setString(2, "b");
    pst.executeUpdate();

        System.out.println("inserted"); }    

        catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e)
        {
          System.out.println(e);
        }

    }       
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe `id` is not a string?  Also how about posting your complete stacktrace so we can see where the error is being thrown from

Comment: ok i am just going to post the complete stacktrace @Scary Wombat

Comment: Please also show the definition of your `STUD1` table

Comment: my output screen i just showing me this:**net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.6 data exception: invalid character value for cast
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
** @ScaryWombat

Comment: you were right@ScaryWombat Id was not a string so that's why i was getting that thing on my output screen......now it's working thanx for guiding me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will get the error

> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.6 data exception: invalid character value for cast

if you try to assign a value to a numeric column via `setString` when the string value cannot be cast to a number. In your case, the [Id] column is almost certainly numeric, but

```java
pst.setString(1, "a");
```

is trying to assign the value "a" to that column, and "a" cannot be converted to a number.